# Не обновляется Android SDK Manager

Tags: android-sdk, android

Ставлю Android Studio. Запускаю SDK Manager. Пытается обновить список доступных обновлений и выдает ошибку:

> Fetching
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
> Failed to fetch URL
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml,
> reason: Connect to
> **dl-ssl.google.com/dl-ssl.google.com/173.194.71.93
> timed out**

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема может быть одна из тысячи возможных. На пример, потеря пакетов, блокировка на стороне провайдера, блокировка через hosts на стороне клиента, не правильно настроенное подключение через прокси, и еще 996 разных причин. 99% что проблема с вашей системой/провайдером/подключением, а ни как не с SDK

Comment: 404. That’s an error.

That’s all we know.